# Different behavior between IIS6 or 7 and VS2010 developpement server with an application MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I have a very big problem with an application developed with mvc3 framework.

In this application I have a reference to a VB6 dll which allow to access to a SQL Server database with ADODB (this is a dll of another application and I can't access directly to the database with .NET).

When I debug my application with Visual Studio development Server I have no problem but if I use IIS (6 or 7) I have an error message (this message is personalized) which show that the database can't be open.

I tested with a console application in VS2010 and it works properly !!

If anybody has an idea I have to deploy my application on Friday before Christmas.

Thank you very much

Comment: You haven't supplied enough information for us to figure out the problem.  Without more information, like the error message, how you have IIS configured (what user it runs as, what mode, etc..), and more informationa bout how this dll accesses the sql database, we can't really make an educated guess.

Comment: Ok excuse me !! For the configuration of IIS I install it and I didn't make particular configuration. Just the selection of the version of .NET framework, and aspnet_regiis. For users, authentication mode is anonymous and the mode of IIS is pipeline. The error message is a custom message so it no longer help you. For access to the database, the VB6 dll uses DAO to open a connection.

Comment: The problem is that my application works correctly with VS2010 developpement server. And the code is in the vb6 dll so I can't debug !!

Comment: you need to find out what the error message is.. how can we help you fix something if we don't know what is wrong?

Comment: I found where is the error. In the VB6 dll, there is a ODBC connection test end an error occured where opening the connection. The error is "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified".

Answer (score 0):

It's fine I have found where was the problem. In fact I use windows 7 in 64 bits and the ODBC Driver used by VB6 dll is 32 bits driver. And the ODBC sourcewas an user source and not a system source so I created a system source and all works fine.